# How to submit form with dynamic html Input texbox using jQuery Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, dynamicform

I'm creating dynamic multiple HTML input box using jQuery and populating the value, after populating I want to update the product price in each text box and submit the form with updated value to server using ajax. I'm facing issue with below code, if I edit the product price in textbox and click on Update button its calling my ajax function, but updated product price not sending to server. I'm getting empty value.

If I click Update button, I'm getting empty array for below code:

```
JSON.stringify($("#updateNameForm").serializeArray())
```

For some reason my dynamic textboxes updated values not coming to ajax method.

Please find my below code - can someone help what I'm doing wrong here and how to resolve the issue.
***Complete code:***

**JSON which comes from server side:**

```
[{
    "productName": "Product1",
    "productPrice": "323"
}, {
    "productName": "Product2",
    "productPrice": "4333"
}]
```

**HTML Code:**

```
<div class="content-wrapper">
  <section class="content">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-9">
        <div class="box box-info">
          <div class="box-header with-border">
            <h3 class="box-title">My Form</h3>
          </div>
          <!-- /.box-header -->
          <form id="updateNameForm" class="form-horizontal" method="post">
            <div class="box-body">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                <div class="checkbox">
                  <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="editName" class="input_control" /> <strong> Edit</strong>
                  </label>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="box-footer">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
              <input id="updateName" type="button" name="updatea" value="Update" class="btn btn-info pull-right">
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

**Update Ajax**

```
$("#updateName").on('click', function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'myApp/updateProduct',
        type: "PUT",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: JSON.stringify($("#updateNameForm").serializeArray()),
        success: function(result) {
            alert(result);
        },
        error: function(e) {
            console.log(e.responseText);
        }
    });
});
```

**loadProduct function**

```
function loadProduct() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'myApp/getProduct',
        type: "GET",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(productJson) {
            $.each(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(productJson)), function(idx, obj) {
                var formgroup = $("<div/>", {
                    class: "form-group"
                });
                formgroup.append($("<label>", {
                    class: "col-sm-2 control-label",
                    text: obj.productName
                }));
                var colsm = $("<div/>", {
                    class: "col-sm-10"
                });
                var input = $("<input/>", {
                    type: "text",
                    class: "form-control",
                    id: obj.productName + "Id",
                    value: obj.productPrice
                });
                colsm.append(input);
                formgroup.append(colsm);
                $(".box-body").append(formgroup);
            });
        },
        error: function(e) {
            console.log(e.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: how did you tell that `but updated product price not sending to server.`?

Comment: I'm getting empty value while submitting the form. I put alert statement - JSON.stringify($("#updateNameForm").serializeArray())  - this returns empty array instead of updated value

Comment: why not use `$("#updateNameForm").serialize()`, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not given `name` to your input field.

```
var input = $("<input/>", {
    type: "text",
    name: "productPrice",
    class: "form-control",
    id: obj.productName + "Id",
    value: obj.productPrice
});
```

Try with above code.